# crontab only running first 2 of multiple python scripts (ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, python, amazon-ec2

I have a crontab in ubuntu (EC2 AWS instance). It runs a different python script on the hour. Each python script ends with a file being overwritten in `/home/ubuntu/bandsintown` via  `writeJSON.write`. After the script does it's thing, I invoke `pkill chrome` (it's selenium script and memory intensive). Crontab below:

```
0 15 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/SF.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)" >> /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/cron.log 2>&1
0 16 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/NYC.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)" >> /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/cron.log 2>&1
0 17 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Austin.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)"  >> /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/cron.log 2>&1
0 18 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Chicago.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)" >> /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/cron.log 2>&1
0 19 * * * /usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Denver.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)" >> /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/cron.log 2>&1
```

Only the first two scripts run (`SF.py and NYC.py`) via crontab, and all py scripts are virtually identical.

**What I've tried:**

1. Made sure all scripts run manually - they do.
2. Make sure the cursor is after the cron script (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277497/multiple-cron-jobs-in-one-crontab-file)).
3. Manually invoked `chmod 775` for .py script and output JSON (the output of the python script). using `ls` in the directory reveals that all the scripts and output files are highlighted green, which seems positive?
4. Tried to write cron results to a log, but this just is outputting a blank file?
5. Checked storage space on ubuntu, again, no obvious issues:

   ```
      /dev/nvme0n1p1  7.7G  4.8G  3.0G  63% /
   ```
6. Investigated cron logs via `journalctl -u cron.service`, (see below) which doesn't raise any red-flags to me.

Thanks.

```
    Jul 26 17:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2777]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 17:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2778]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Austin.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headles
    Jul 26 17:07:06 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2777]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
    Jul 26 17:07:06 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2777]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
    Jul 26 17:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2896]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 17:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[2896]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
    Jul 26 18:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3244]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 18:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3245]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Chicago.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headle
    Jul 26 18:05:51 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3244]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
    Jul 26 18:05:51 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3244]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
    Jul 26 18:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3525]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 18:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3525]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
    Jul 26 18:44:01 ip-172-31-31-200 cron[826]: (ubuntu) RELOAD (crontabs/ubuntu)
    Jul 26 19:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3901]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 19:00:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3902]: (ubuntu) CMD (/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/ubuntu/bandsintown/Denver.py ; pkill chrome ; pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headles
    Jul 26 19:03:02 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3901]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
    Jul 26 19:03:02 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[3901]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
    Jul 26 19:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[4013]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Jul 26 19:17:01 ip-172-31-31-200 CRON[4013]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

**UPDATE:**

I re-directed the output so that not just the `pkill` command is being output, and it appears the problem is the python script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/LA.py", line 401, in <module>
    with open("/home/ubuntu/bandsintown/LA_events.json", "w") as writeJSON:
PermissionError: [Errno 13]
```

How is this issue solved, a `chmod` command?

Comment: Re. (4) you are only writing the output of `pkill -f "(chrome)?(--headless)"` to the log file

Comment: yes, I will update this. But the crontab still shouldn't fail right?

Comment: Does any of the jobs take more than a minute to run?  If one job needs to finish before the next one runs, then make sure to schedule them with enough time in-between them, or run them sequentially from a single script that you schedule once only.

Comment: 1. instead of running half a dozen python scripts from cron, 1 minute apart, try writing a shell script wrapper that runs each of the python scripts one after the other and run that from cron - then it won't matter how long each one takes.   2. If the python scripts are almost identical, rewrite it as one script that takes an argument of SF, NYC, Austin, etc.   This would reduce duplication of code (which is often a source of errors when duplicate scripts aren't updated in sync) and allow the shell wrapper to be written as a loop `for city in SF NYC ...; do python-script "$city"; done`

Comment: Also, does your script really need to run chrome (presumably a selenium web bot)?  Can it get away with using something like [urllib](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org) or [mechanize](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/index.html) (for an entirely python solution)?  or just fork `curl`?   Usually, selenium is only needed if you need to test or interact with a website as if you were a normal user running a web browser and/or run javascript....but forking chrome is very heavy-weight if all you need is to fetch a URL.

Comment: As pointed out, my first guess is that the scrips _do_ run, but the time it takes to load and run the Chrome Selenium exceeds the one minute interval, and they "bang heads". Try to rework your scenario to run one single cron job that performs each job in turn, waits for it to complete, and then goes on to the next, exiting only when all the jobs are done.

Comment: Given your other question, I would guess that some of the cron jobs are failing because the cron job is running as root but the files they're trying to write to are owned by root.   fixing the ownership (as shown in my answer) should solve that problem.

Comment: Also, you should probably install a Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) if you're going to be running cron jobs.   cron will mail the output (both stdout and stderr) to the user running the cron job, unless the output is redirected (to a file or /dev/null).   You probably don't need a full-featured MTA like [postfix](http://www.postfix.org) or [exim](https://www.exim.org/), Something small and simple like [DMA](https://github.com/corecode/dma) or [esmtp](http://esmtp.sourceforge.net/)  will do - either of those can deliver to local mailboxes or forward mail to a remote mail server.